# which html elements have a default action that can be prevented by preventDefault

Tags: html, preventdefault

I'm trying to figure out which html elements have a default action that can be prevented by calling preventDefault(). I cannot find it in the specs. Where is it specified?

Comment: Every element which you can interact with...

Comment: Buttons, Submit-Buttons and Links for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell:
preventDefault() makes it such that any action(s) that would happen, if the javascript was turned off, are suppressed/blocked.

All the rest I could mention is already mentioned by the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure it's specified, though I imagine it is; but default actions seem to result from user-behaviour/-interaction; so a rule of thumb would be: 'if a use can interact, and do something, with this element there's probably a default action expected of this element/interaction.'

Though I can't cite a source for this supposition as yet, unfortunately.